# Does ASP.NET MVC's JsonResult use reflection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, reflection

Does ASP.NET MVC's JsonResult use reflection to work out what Json to return ?

I'm asking the question because on the particular project I'm working on at the moment I've already run into problems with reflection. The hosting provider I'm having to use doesn't allow reflection and so I had to rewrite alot of code that was making use of [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) which uses reflection.

Comment: I would switch host if I were you ;) there are plenty (even cheap ones) that do allow it.

Comment: Not really my choice I'm afraid, that is up to the client, can only recommend. Don't suppose there is a list of ones that do support reflection (you would never know from the current host's website that the service was in any way restricted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does ASP.NET MVC's JsonResult use reflection to work out what Json to return

It uses the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class which in turns uses reflection to cycle through the properties of model. Excerpt from it's [ExecuteResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.executeresult.aspx) method:

```
...
if (this.Data != null)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    response.Write(serializer.Serialize(this.Data));
}
```